# Server responds with 404 when trying to connect Socket.io to an Express app

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, vuejs2

I'm building a VueJS app using vue-cli's webpack template.
I've split the front and back ends into different Heroku applications and deployed them.

**Background:**
My client app has the same setup as described [here](https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489)

**tl;dr the above Medium article:**
We now have a fresh Vue-cli/webpack app, and a server.js file used to create an Express server that serves the built app files.

**The problem:**
I've been running into issues trying to use socket.io on said server.js file.

Here's how `server.js` looks like:

```
var http = require('http'),
        path = require('path'),
        express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        server = http.createServer(app),
        socketIO = require('socket.io'),
        port = process.env.PORT || 8080,
        history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
        serveStatic = require('serve-static')


app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))

server.listen(port, () => {
    // logs when running node server.js
    console.log('listening on port', port)
})

const io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connected!!!');
});
```

And this is how I call socket.io inside of my `.vue` component:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080')
```

As soon as this last line is uncommented I receive a friendly `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M9yJX8nsocket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M9yHe0F`

**Additional info:**

Not sure if relevant, but still saying - I'm Using "connect-history-api-fallback" to point all non-existent routes to a wildcard 404 `.vue` component that displays a friendly user message and allows them to go back to existing routes. 
Can this be a part of the reason? What I read about my issue is that I probably have trouble making socket.io run on the same server that my app is running in.

I experienced the problem initially when trying to first connect my Vue App with [Vue-Socket.io](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/)

upon the line

```
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://socketserver.com:1923'));
```

Where as an URL I used `http://localhost:8080`

I've spend a good few days on the problem and still have no clarity on where this problem is rooted in. I am really trying to understand and would highly appreciate any form of feedback. I read about people having the same / similar problem, and tried calling `io()` without my localhost + port url.

First question here, hope it's properly asked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guys, I don't know why, but following the code placed in the "Docs" section of Socket IO's website resulted in the same error (Express 3/4 section). I then went on to copy the Chat demo and **had success**, so I'm now importing Socket.IO in my Index.html file

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

With `server.js` looking like this:

```
var path = require('path'),
    app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080,
    history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static')

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))

http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port', port)
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connected!!!');
});
```

I'm going to close this now and see how to implement the functionality I'm looking for - I now have a good starting point. Best of luck to anyone struggling with this.
Cheers!